# How to debug `ng build`?

Tags: angular, ng-build

I am getting `ERROR in Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element.` error after running `ng build` with `"optimization": true` parameter. (If I disabled the optimization flag the build will pass but resulted with like 20mb large `vendor.js` file!)

I had searched online that the error indicated some css format issue. However, even I pass the `--verbose` flag, angular won't give me the proper information about which `css` file angular failed to parse. What can I do to make angular give me more relevant information? For this project, there are over a thousand searched results for `:`, it's not so practical to debug manually. Also this is an angular 9 project.

Comment: try searching for colon and a space `: `, it seems like the most possible mistake

Comment: There are still over 1300 results searching `: `, and I believe `:` without space are the root cause?

Comment: Maybe search in your node module folder for the file throwing the `Expected a pseudo-class` error, then temporarily modify that file to add debug info

Comment: There are 0 result for this search. Searching `pseudo-class` or `pseudo-element` alone is not helpful as wel.